# How does Podio works in SandBox?

Tags: podio

I'm just looking to make some integrations with Podio and I need to use the sandbox. I want to know if the sandbox is a kind of delayed copy of the production data or something else because when I use it I get production environment information, so I don't know if I modify some info for testing purposes that will change productive data.

I searched this in the documentation and asked Podio support channels but with no success.

Comment: May i ask why you need to use sandbox? If it is data you want to process as you can do it in the podio sandbox, you can always use API for this purpose.

Comment: I wan't to give access to an external developers team to make some tests so I need an environment similar to a production one but with no chance of delete or modify real productive information.

Comment: Just to be safe, its best to make a dev environment. Even though podio keep revisions, its best the  keep the environments apart

Comment: Thanks! I finally did it, I think is not ideal because we'll need to sync structural changed between environments, but is still a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

The sandbox functionality offered on the API documentation seems to just provide a means of experimenting with calls to the Podo API via a simple web interface.

I have just tested it and confirm it seems to operate on live production data.

However, this 'sandbox' functionality only works with GET requests. If you go to the DELETE or UPDATE item method page, it says, 'The sandbox only handles GET operations for now.' So it seems you won't harm your production data since it is read-only.

Comment: Oh I see, it make a lot of sense to me... I think my best chance is to replicate mi environment but is far away from a good solution.

Thanks!